# How would I add another not equal (!=) to this statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, equals, key-value

How would I add another not equal (!=) value to this statement?

```
if ($(this).data("increase_priority1") && $(this).val() != 1)
```

I tried reversing the syntax at the beginning of the function which determines if it is equal, but that stopped it from removing items completely (including those not equaling 1)

```
if ($(this).data("increase_priority1") && $(this).val() != 1 && $(".complaint select").val() != "Too_small")
```

This function adds and/or remove values from "increase_priority1" when the user has selected both a complaint and ranked the importance level of the issue, and I need it to change the value (in this case what the complaint is) and importance level (i.e. increase_priority1) if either of those 2 fields changes. At the moment it only changes when the importance level changes.

The full function is:

```
var $increase_priority1 = $(".increase_priority1");
$('.ranking, .complaint select').dropkick({
change: function () {
    var name = $(this)
        .data("name"); //get priority name
    if ($(".complaint select")
        .val() === "Too_small" && $(this)
        .val() == 1 && !$(this)
        .data("increase_priority1")) {
        //rank is 1, and not yet added to priority list
        $("<option>", {
            text: name,
            val: name
        })
            .appendTo($increase_priority1);
        $(this)
            .data("increase_priority1", true); //flag as a priority item
    }
    if ($(this)
        .data("increase_priority1") && $(this)
        .val() != 1) {
        //is in priority list, but now demoted
        $("option[value=" + name + "]", $increase_priority1)
            .remove();
        $(this)
            .removeData("increase_priority1"); //no longer a priority item
    }
}
});
```

Fiddle which shows this in context: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/vWLEn/132/

Comment: I don't understand the question...

Comment: Do you perhaps mean to remove elements for which `$(this).val() != 1` **OR** `$(".complaint select").val() != "Too_small"`?

Comment: @Kninnug I need to remove elements when either one of those statements isn't true. Would that be an OR statement instead of AND?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct, an OR-operation is true when at least one of the operands is true (possibly both!). Your statement should be: `if ($(this).data("increase_priority1") && ($(this).val() != 1 || $(".complaint select").val() != "Too_small"))`. `||` is the Javascript-syntax for an OR.

Comment: @Kninnug Thank you!!! I normally wouldn't have asked, but another problem with the code wasn't allowing me to properly test it (I'm having trouble triggering the function when the complaint element changes).

Comment: You're right, I should have done so in the first place. (: I've posted a (more comprehensive) answer below for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An OR-operation is true when at least one of the operands is true (possibly both!). Your statement should be:

```
if ($(this).data("increase_priority1") && 
    ($(this).val() != 1 || $(".complaint select").val() != "Too_small")).
```

`||` is the Javascript-syntax for an OR.

This will run the `if` if `.data("increase_priority1")` is true **and** `$(this).val() != 1` **or** `$(".complaint select").val() != "Too_small")` is true.

Note that the interpreter will stop if the first part of the `&&` is false, that is to say: it will not even look at the second part. It is the same for the `||`, but the other way around, so if the first part of the `||` is true it will not look at the second part.

Comment: Thank you for both your really helpful answer and your incredibly clear and useful explanation :-)

Comment: You're very welcome, that's what Stackoverflow is for. (:

Comment: :-D I'm looking forward to the day that I can answer more questions than I ask :-)

Comment: I spoke a bit too soon :-( The function seems to require my specifying which .complaint select value to use and isn't working with id's (which would have been cumbersome to work with anyway). Any chance that you can show me how to call it here by another means, like (this)?

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite follow, perhaps you should open another question for that.

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to do, but figured I should check with you first ;-) If I'm lucky, another awesome Stackoverflow member will help me learn another new thing tonight :-D